# Как присоединить частицу (суффикс) или приставку к названию, заключённому в кавычки?

Tags: орфография, кавычки, названия, дефис, оформление-текста

Скажите, как правильно оформить название (книги, например) в кавычках, если к нему надо пристыковать частицу "то"? Да и вообще, что угодно пристыковать: до или после. Как это оформить? Стыкующаяся часть тоже должна быть заключена в кавычки или нет? С одной стороны, если мы стыкуем нечто со словом прямо внутри кавычек, мы же по сути изменяем название! А с другой, не странно ли выглядит сочетание кавычки и дефиса? Впрочем, в кроссворде (да, так себе источник, но всё же, как пример) видел такое: **самолёт-"этажерка"**. Есть какое-то чёткое правило на этот счёт?

*Михаил вышел из подъезда, а в руках у него было "Преступление". Так и хотелось спросить: "Ну а **"Войну и мир"-то** / **"Войну и мир-то"** куда дел, а?"*

*Читал я это ваше **супер-пупер-"Мы"** / **"супер-пупер-Мы"**.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (22.10.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила на схожий вопрос № 224690 (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20224690)) и подтвердила, что такая конструкция верна: **бутылка-"стакан"**, то есть по аналогии верно и **самолёт-"этажерка"**.

Что касается проблемы с "-то", оказывается, им уже задавали вопрос на эту тему, и вот, что они ответили на вопрос № 294987 (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=294987)):

> Рекомендаций для подобных случаев в справочниках по правописанию пока нет. Из предложенных Вами вариантов лучше второй. Он выглядит диковинно, но не искажает названия, как в первом варианте. Однако более предпочтительным представляется написание без знака препинания: *А ты «Мертвые души» то читал?*  Когда приставка или часть сложного слова, требующая слитного написания, присоединяется к словосочетанию, она пишется раздельно. Ср.: *лже доктор наук*, *псевдо произведение искусства*, *теле круглый стол*, *мини стиральная машина*; *экс Советский Союз*, *псевдо Ван Гог*, *пол рабочего дня*, *пол столовой ложки*, *пол Московской области*. Это правило можно распространить и на написание постфикса *то*, присоединяемого к словосочетанию.
> Спасибо за очень интересный вопрос. Мы передадим его в Орфографическую комиссию РАН.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно, само правило уже заключено в слове "постфикс": postfixum — «прикреплённое после. Я не встречал отдельного правила для истории с кавычками. Возможно, оно нигде и не сформулировано. Однако кавычки заключают цитату, а постфикс частью этой цитаты (или названия чего-либо) не является. Отсюда вы можете пойти от обратного и обратить внимание на то, что ни одно правило не позволяет вам доращивать в цитаты и названия посторонние элементы. Названия можно только склонять или сокращать.

Здесь важно не столько найти на каждую ситуацию правило от Розенталя, сколько понимать, что внутри кавычек находится чужой текст, как бы цитируемый, а за их пределами находится авторский (автора фразы). То есть Чехов называет свой рассказ "Дама с собачкой", и это сочетание слов навсегда останется незыблемой авторской цитатой, куда нельзя вмешиваться, покуда мы говорим об этом самом рассказе. И если кто-то пишет текст об этой "Даме с собачкой", то все псевдо-, недо-, -то и т.д. останутся вынесенными за пределы этих кавычек, потому что сам Чехов придумал сочетание слов, в котором их не имелось.