# О чём позориться в «Монологе и позабытой дружбе»(-)то?

Tags: дефис

Нужен этот дефис?

> О чём позориться в «Монологе и позабытой дружбе»(-)то?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как присоединить частицу (суффикс) или приставку к названию, заключённому в кавычки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470941/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b)